# Differentiation problem

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Lecturer give a example with answer, but I think there is a problem with the question.

Question

> x^2 e^(a y - b x) - sin(a x + c y^2) = 0
>   a, b and c are constants and x, y are variables.
>   Calculate the ∂y/∂x
>   Use Dt and Solve Functions

can you fix my answer?

My answer

```
S10 =  x^2 E^(a y - b x) - Sin[a x + c y^2]
Solve[S10 == 0, {x}]
Solve[S10 == 0, {y}]
Dt[S10, y]/Dt[S10, x]
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localised and unlikely to help other users, and contains a misunderstanding easily solved by information found in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be instructor meant this?

```
ClearAll[x, y, a, b]
eq = x^2 Exp[a y[x] - b x] - Sin[a x + c y[x]^2] == 0;
Dt[eq, x, Constants -> {a, b,c}];
Solve[%, y'[x]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

I think the point is

```
dbydx = Dt[x^2 E^(a y - b x) - Sin[a x + c y^2], x, Constants -> {a, b, c}]
Solve[ dbydx ==0, Dt[y, x, Constants -> {a, b, c}]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I think İt is also true answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is always many way to arrive to the same solution. As the last commer I give the doc way --- have a look to http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Differentiation.html

```
S10 = x^2 E^(a y - b x) - Sin[a x + c y^2]
Solve[D[S10, x, NonConstants -> {y}] == 0, 
 D[y, x, NonConstants -> {y}]]
```

Ps Never begin a variable by a capital letter in Mathematica. First capital letter are reserved to commands.

Comment: Thank you dear Comments. I will